# how to write async redux actions in a non-fake app

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

**tl;dr:** I need an example of an asynchronous redux-thunk action shows how to make an async call (e.g. `fetch`), and trigger a state update. I also need to see how someone might chain multiple such actions together, like: (1) see if user exists in cloud, then (2) if no, register them, then (3) use the new user record to fetch more data.

---

All the examples I've found makes the assumption that the redux store can be imported directly into the module that defines the actions. It's my understanding that this is a bad practice: the calling component is responsible for providing access to the store, via `this.props.dispatch` (which comes from the store being injected via the `<Provider>`).

Instead, every action in the redux world should return a function that will receive the appropriate `dispatch`; that function should do the work, and return... something. Obv, it matters what the something is.

Here's the pattern I've tried, based on the documentation, that has proven to be a failure. Nothing in the docs makes it clear why this doesn't work, but it doesn't -- because this action doesn't return a promise.

```
/**
 * pushes a new user into the cloud; once complete, updates the store with the new user row
 * @param  {hash} user - of .firstName, .lastName
 * @return {promise} resolves with user { userId, firstName, lastName, dateCreated }, or rejects with error
 */
Actions.registerUser = function(user) {
    return function reduxAction(dispatch) {
        return API.createUser(user) // API.createUser just does return fetch(...)
        .then(function onUserRegistered(newUser) {
            return dispatch({
                type: 'ADD_USERS',
                users: [newUser]
            });
        });
    };
};
```

I have a reducer that responds to the `ADD_USERS` event; it merges the incoming array of one or more users with the array of users already in memory. Reducers are easy to write. That's why I switched to redux: one store, pure functions. But this thunk business is an absolute nightmare.

The error I receive is that `.then` is undefined on `Actions.registerUser` -- i.e. that `Actions.registerUser` doesn't return a promise.

I think the problem is obviously that I'm returning a function -- the `reduxAction` function -- but that doesn't seem to be negotiable. The only way to shoot data at the store is to use the `dispatch` method that is provided, and that means I can't return a promise.

Changing the `onUserRegistered` to simply *invoke* dispatch and then return the desired value doesn't work either, nor does having it return an actual promise.

PLZ HALP. I really don't get it. I can't believe people put up with all this.

---

**EDIT**: To provide some context, here's the kind of action composition I think I'm supposed to be able to perform, and which these thunk actions are frustrating:

```
Actions.bootSetup = function() {
    return dispatch => {
        return Actions.loadUserId() // looks for userId in local storage, or generates a new value
        .then(Actions.storeUserId) // pushes userId into local storage
        .then((userId) => {
            return Actions.fetchUsers(userId) // fetches the user, by id, from the cloud
            .then((user) => {
                // if necessary, pushes the user into the cloud, too
                return user || Actions.postUser({ userId: userId, firstName: 'auto-registered', lastName: 'tbd'}); 
            });
        })
        .then((user) => {
            console.log(`boot sequence complete with user `, user);
            return dispatch({ type: 'ADD_OWNER', user });
        });
    };
};
```

I would expect that `Actions.storeUserId` and `Actions.fetchUsers` would, in addition to returning promises that resolve with values of my choosing, dispatch data to the store as a side-effect. I think the dispatch is occurring, but the chain breaks because none of these actions return promises - they return plain functions.

Not only does this seem much worse than Flux, it seems incomprehensible. I can't believe that all this madness was necessary just to consolidate app state into a single reducing store.

And yes -- I have tried the new version of flux, with its ReducerStore, but it has some inappropriate dependencies on CSS libraries that are incompatible with react-native. The project maintainers have said they don't intend to resolve the issue. I guess their state container is dependent on CSS functionality.

---

**EDIT**: my store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import Reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleWare = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);


export const initialState = {
    users: [] // will hold array of user objects
};

const store = createStoreWithMiddleWare(Reducers);

export default store;
```

---

**EDIT**: Here's the calling code. This is the root-level react-native component.

```
// index.ios.js
import Store from './store';

class myApp extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        Store.dispatch(Actions.bootSetup())
        .then(() => {
            console.log('*** boot complete ***');
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={Store}>
                <ApplicationRoutes />
            </Provider>
        );
    }

}
```

My assumption is that `Store.dispatch` expects a function, and provides it with a reference to the store's dispatch method.

Comment: Can you show how you wired up the `thunk` middleware in your `createStore`?

Comment: Can you also show the calling code?

Comment: If you haven't read the docs I strongly suggest it. Specifically, [this page](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) which answers your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see one mistake right off the bat

```
Actions.bootSetup = function() {
    return dispatch => {
        return Actions.loadUserId()
```

You aren't chaining thunk actions correctly. If your actions returns a function, you need to pass dispatch to that action.

Take a look at this [action creator](https://github.com/tyrsius/coral-commons/blob/master/src%2Fauth%2Factions.js#L156-L174)(this is a fully functional real-world app, feel free to poke around), look at the 9th line, where `loginUser` is called.

```
export function changePassword(credentials) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(changePasswordStart(credentials))
        return Firebase.changePassword(credentials)
            .then(() => {
                return logout()
            })
            .then(() => {
                return loginUser(credentials.email, credentials.newPassword)(dispatch)
            })
            .then(() => {
                    dispatch(changePasswordSuccess(credentials))
                    toast.success('Password successfully changed')
            }).catch(error => {
                    dispatch(changePasswordError(error.code))
                    toast.error('An error occured changing your password: ' + error.code)
            })
    }
}
```

Because `loginUser` is also a thunk action, it needs to have dispatch passed to the result of calling it. It makes sense if you think about it: the thunk doesn't do anything, it just creates a function. You need to call the function it returns to get it to do the action. Since the function it returns takes `dispatch` as an argument, you need to pass that in as well.

Once that's done, returning a promise from a thunk action will work. In fact, the example I gave above does exactly that. `loginUser` returns a promise, as does `changePassword`. Both are thenables.

Your code probably needs to look like this (though I am not sure, I don't have the actions being called)

```
Actions.bootSetup = function() {
    return dispatch => {
        return Actions.loadUserId()(dispatch) // pass dispatch to the thunk
        .then(() => Actions.storeUserId(dispatch)) // pass dispatch to the thunk
        .then((userId) => {
            return Actions.fetchUsers(userId)(dispatch) // pass dispatch to the thunk
            .then((user) => {
                // pass dispatch to the thunk
                return user || Actions.postUser({ userId: userId, firstName: 'auto-registered', lastName: 'tbd'})(dispatch); 
            });
        })
        .then((user) => {
            console.log(`boot sequence complete with user `, user);
            return dispatch({ type: 'ADD_OWNER', user });
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: This was exactly the problem. It also confirmed for me that it's not necessary to `return dispatch(...)` -- just as in Flux, one wouldn't `return Dispatcher.dispatch(...)` -- it's a side-effect, so you can still return whatever data makes sense for the action.

Comment: It can be useful to return the thunk promise for exactly this case: other actions can't chain properly if the action they are calling doesn't return a thenable. I recommend always returning the promise from a thunk action

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "the thunk promise." I agree that it's useful if all these methods can be relied upon to return thenables; does `dispatch` return a promise?

Comment: No, dispatch doesn't return a promise. The thunk promise is the function returned by `boolSetup` or `postUser`. These should `return dispatch => {}`